# Passing a variable inside quotation marks to a command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Some context :

I'm attempting to run a command as part of a bash script to poll for system/device data.

```
# Recommended usage in the command line, contains single and double quotes
wbemcli ein 'http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class'
wbemcli gi 'http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class.DeviceID="Some Device ID"'

# I can get away with just 1 level of quotation marks
wbemcli ein http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class
wbemcli gi http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class.DeviceID="Some Device ID"
wbemcli gi http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class.DeviceID='Some Device ID'
```

So this is working ...

```
    #!/bin/sh

    C_PATH=http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2
    CLASS=some_class
    ID="Some Device ID"

    set -x
    wbemcli ein $C_PATH:$CLASS
```

Unfortunately, it falls apart when I attempt to integrate the quotation marks into the command. The code executed in the shell is unexpected to me.

```
    # Code
    wbemcli gi $C_PATH:$CLASS.DeviceID=\"$ID\"

    output $ ./myscript
    + wbemcli gi 'http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class.DeviceID="Some' Device 'ID"'

    # I was expecting this ...
    output $ ./myscript
    + wbemcli gi http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2:some_class.DeviceID="Some Device ID"
```

Bash is adding quotation marks in places I didn't expect. It's even enclosing the entire URL portion in single quotation marks. What's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
wbemcli gi -nl "$C_PATH:$CLASS.DeviceID=\"$ID\""
```

or like this:

```
wbemcli gi -nl "$C_PATH:$CLASS.DeviceID='$ID'"
```

Comment: 1st one gives `+ wbemcli gi -nl 'C_PATH:some_class.DeviceID="Some Device ID"'` and 2nd one gives `+ wbemcli gi -nl 'C_PATH:some_class.DeviceID='\''Some Device ID'\'''`

Comment: @peonicles: Both the traces are OK — the `wbemcli` command gets to see either single quotes or double quotes around the 'Some Device ID' and sees the whole string as a single argument even though there are spaces in 'Some Device ID'.  `bash` does echo things differently under `set -x` from other shells; its output is typically unambiguous where other shells' output is ambiguous.

Comment: ahh ok, I had a really dumb syntax error (omitted the $ in $C_PATH). #1 is working perfectly, thanks guys!

#2 is still adding the weird `'\'` though.

Comment: That's just how bash displays the string when you have `set -x` enabled. It's the string `C_PATH:some_class.DeviceID=`, followed by a literal single quote `\'`, the string `Some Device ID`, another literal single quote `\'` and the empty string `''`. You get this weird-looking representation, because nested single quotes can't be escaped in single-quoted strings.

Comment: I've substituted in actual values into the variables, and #1 is working nicely. #2 seems to give me a usable string when I echo, but for some reason wbemcli is giving me errors. Your answer should work for other similar situations though.

Comment: Perhaps `wbemcli` is unhappy about the single quotes around the ID.